# How to loop in VBA UDF with if statement?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, user-defined-functions

[image]

I have written VBA user define function which take two parameters as selected cell values. As show in picture if value of B3 (Parameter 1) is matching with value I2 (Parameter 2) then it should return A3 (Date) + B3(Number of weeks) in I3.

If not match then return "". As next steps, Parameter 1 should take offset of 1 and go to C3 and check again whether C3 (now Parameter 1) is matching with I2 (Parameter 2).

Entire For loop should run until H2. When use the function it shows Value error and in debugging, I found out that i from for loop is not getting next value and stays with i = 1. any help?

---

```
Function expedia(cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range) As Date
Dim i As Integer, o_date As Date
For i = 1 To 8  
    If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then  
        o_date = DateAdd("ww", cell1.Value, Range("A3"))  
    End If  
    cell1.Value = cell1.Offset(0, i).Value
Next i
expedia = o_date

End Function
```

---

[image]

Comment: In UDF it is not permitted to take actions only calculations. This is MS info about the subject [Detailed info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f)

Comment: Was wondering if you could use a formula in cell `I3` as `=IF(I2=B3,$A$3+I2*7,"")` and copy across?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij has a good point.  Do you need to use VBA for this?